# 403 Forbidden , AWS API and Clouflare

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, cloudflare

this message Forbidden appeared when I send a POST request to the my API domainX.com, domainX.com has a CNAME = domain.com , but when I send the same request to domain.com , everything works

POST domainX.com ->

```
{
   "message" : "Forbidden"
}
```

here is the body

```
{
   "Alt-Svc" : "h3=\":443\"; ma=86400",
   "x-amzn-errortype" : "ForbiddenException",
   "cf-cache-status" : "DYNAMIC",
   "report-to" : "{\"endpoints\":[{\"url\":\"https:\\/\\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\\/report\\/v3?s= TIorlOinjSbbqWzpoAjpHanzEY%2FDWQ13qDdHIGgKuK0nVl167LS%2FBCt7iXUDLP3TOlPBp8lUO1tzEIKE0LgWPckI%2BQz1DnoOhAy523k2tmAMHQSmw%2FWH%2FZms%3D\"}],\"group\":\"cf-nel\",\"max_age\":604800 }",
   "Server" : "cloudflare",
   "x-amz-apigw-id" : "HlwO8CC224FiAFb0Q=",
   "nel" : "{\"success_fraction\":0,\"report_to\":\"cf-nel\",\"max_age\":602800}",
   "x-amzn-requestid" : "88fs2ac2-88XXd-4819-a695-203e777c781",
   "Content-Length" : "23",
   "cf-ray" : "7e1f9473666325c-VIE",
   "Content-Type" : "application/json",
   "Date" : "Wed, 05 Jul 2023 12:23:33 GMT"
}
```

I'm trying to proxy requests to domain.com through cloudflare, there can be no problems with authorization, because the same request is successful on domain.com